# Not able to serve static files using res.Send() while using fetch() API

Tags: javascript, express, fetch-api

I have created a backend API in express for handling user login. In the frontend I am collecting the credentials using an HTML form. Then, I am making a POST request to the backend API for login using Fetch() API. After that is done successfully, I make another GET request to basically redirect the user to another page `'/create-chat'`.

This is the frontend logic:

```js
const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
let accessToken = "";

loginForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let formData = new FormData(loginForm); // getting the form data
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

  const form = e.currentTarget;
  const url = form.action; // the URL to the backend API is coming from the action attribute of the form
  
  // POST request to the login API
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
  accessToken = result.accessToken; // this access token is successfully returned by the login API

  // GET request to the /create-chat route
  fetch("/create-chat", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken, // access token is required, to access this route
    },
  });
});
```

Here's the /create-chat route in the backend:

```js
app.get("/create-chat", isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  try {
    console.log("in create chat handler"); // this is getting executed
    res.sendFile(path.resolve("public/create-chat.html")); // not working
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending file:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

The `isAutheticated` middleware simply checks if there's a valid access token in the authorization header, which it is doing perfectly and giving no errors. The `console.log()` inside the handler for `/create-chat` is getting executed too. But it is not serving the `create-chat.html` page as expected by the `res.Send()`.

I am assuming the problem lies not in the backend, but with how I am accessing the `/create-chat` route from the frontend using fetch() API. If, for instance, I set `window.location.href = response.url;` after I call the create-chat route and return from it, it will again call the `/create-chat` route and again run the middleware.
I need to serve the static file `create-chat.html` as well as redirect to `/create-chat` url.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your code shows `fetch("/create-chat", ...)`, but doesn't show doing anything with the response that comes back in your Javascript.  `fetch()` ONLY gets content back to your Javascript.  It does not display anything in the browser.  If you want the result of `/create-chat` to show in the browser, then do `window.location.href = "/create-chat";` and that will tell the browser to both load and display that page.  Of course, if you need an Auth header, you can't do it that way.  Auth headers shouldn't be used for browser displayed pages.  They are for programmatic pages.

Comment: @jfriend00 But, I am using `fetch()` just to call my route from the front end and not display the contents of the page. To serve my static file, I am using `res.Send()`, which is not behaving as expected, probably due to some problem posed by `fetch()`? If the `/create-chat` handler is getting executed, why is the static file not being displayed?

Comment: @jfriend00 Also, if it is not advised to use the middleware (that's what is consuming the Auth headers) with the browser page, how else should I ensure that the user isn't able to access `/create-chat` before logging in and generating a valid access token? I am new to this and still learning, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @HarshitTiwari "*why is the static file not being displayed?*" - you've answered that question yourself: "*I am using fetch() [to] not display the contents of the page.*" The problem is not with serving the file, it's just that your frontend code is not displaying the response.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that when you send a `fetch()` call from your Javascript. 
the static file is coming back to your Javascript.  It's right there for your Javascript as the response to the `fetch()` call.  The browser NEVER displays results from a `fetch()` call.  That response goes back only to your Javascript.  Also, I don't know why you keep saying you're using `res.Send()` which isn't even a method with the capital S.  Your code is using `res.sendFile()` which is perfectly fine, but `fetch()` just returns the content back to your Javascript no matter what you do on your server.

Comment: When you want to authenticate pages that the browser loads, then the server usually sets a cookie with auth credentials in it on the browser and then your middleware checks for the existence of the cookie.  This is how nearly all sites do authentication for web-site browsing.  `res.cookie(...)` from your server will set a cookie into a response that the browser will store and automatically send with future requesets.  Then, `req.cookies` can be examined on the server to check incoming requests.